# Qubes - Create New Qube VM - Networking Setup

Tags: networking, qubes

While creating new Qube VM in Qubes OS,
there is a networking setup that we need to choose.
The options are `sys-firewall`, `sys-net`, `sys-usb`, `sys-whonix`, `none`.
Anyone know the difference between these options?

How if we choose `none`, does it mean, the VM will have no internet connection?
I am assuming that `sys-firewall`, is referring to existing system firewall setup, is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

- `None` = Qube will have no access.
- `Whonix` = Routes traffic through
  Whonix gateway (all traffic via Tor)
- `sys-net` = Will connect to the internet through sys-net gateway
- `sys-firewall` = Will connect via the configurable firewall

you must configure the firewall for it do do any good.